# Floating Element beneath Table with Firefox

Tags: firefox, html-table, mozilla, floating

I want to float an element beneath a table. The table has 100% in width, so the expected output is the floated element to appear above the table. Everything is fine with all major browser engines except of Mozilla.

Is there a way to force Firefox for a line break only with CSS? I have no chance to alter the HTML code so a solution with CSS would be very important.

Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div {
  background: red;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
}
table { width: 100%; }
td { background: green; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>Label</div>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            Table
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fPVcr/

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
table {
    clear: right;
}
```

That will ensure that the table is rendered beneath the floating element, but beware: if there are any other elements, specified before the table, which are floating on the right, the table will also render after those.